# python class inheritance for parameters

Tags: python, inheritance, parameters, init

I am trying to create a schedule class in python that takes the start time, end time, and location of a meeting. So far I have:

```
class Schedule(Time):
def __init__(self, start_time, end_time, location):
    self.start_time = start_time
    self.end_time = end_time
    self.location = location
    print (self.start_time)
    print (self.end_time)
    print (self.location)
```

I have a Time class completed which looks like this:

```
class Time():
    def __init__(self, init_hr = 12, init_min = 0, init_ampm = "AM"):
        self.hr = init_hr
        self.min = init_min
        self.ampm = init_ampm
```

Now I want to be able to make the parameters start_time and end_time (from the initialization of schedule) to be Time instances, however I'm confused on how I would go about doing that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of inventing your own Time class, try using classes from the `datetime` module.

Comment: And what you have defined as "Schedule" is really just one Event or Meeting or Appointment, of which a Schedule would contain many.

Comment: Are you *sure* your `Schedule` class **is a** kind of `Time`?  If that's so, how come it needs two times to be created?  Could it be possible that instead, they are totally different kinds of things, but `Schedule` **has a** few `Time` objects as part of its design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some dynamically-typed languages would want you to do this everywhere (statically-typed languages will generally enforce it themselves), but in Python the generally recommended practice is [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), which suggests that you just expect it to be a Time, but if it's something else, don't worry (if it implements the same interface as Time, well and good, if it doesn't, let it fail when you try accessing attributes that don't exist on the object). The general idea there is that you are expected to be intelligent enough to know what you're doing.

If a I were writing this code, I would leave it as you have it, with a few notes:

- As others have mentioned, change `class Schedule(Time)` to `class Schedule(object)`.
- In `Time.__init__`, don't call your parameters `init_hr`, etc., just call them `hr`, etc. Python ain't Java, where you've got to use different names or always refer to the class version as `this.*`. In Python, you *always* use `self.*`. Python also has keyword arguments - so you could have `Time(hr=4, ...)`; `Time(init_hr=4, ...)` would be ugly.
- If you're in Python 2, change `print (...)` to `print ...`. If you're in Python 3, change it to `print(...)`.

Comment: changing class Schedule(Time) to (object) gives me what I'm looking for, however I have never seen that used. Out of curiosity, what exactly is (object) doing differently?

Comment: @Flames1991 In python (<2.2) object wasn't used and classes implementation was different from the current one. When new style classes were available, it was needed to explicitly subclass from object to make it clear that new style classes were used (and don't break old code). You can find more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/183066).

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want Schedule to be a subclass of Time; the relationship between the two is most likely "has a" rather than "is a". Just make it a subclass of `object` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to change anything in your code.

However, you can:

- Document it to make it clear the expected type of the parameters (I recommend [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) for that).
- Write assertions to make sure the type passed matches your expectations (`assert isinstance(variable, type)`). You can even use some more advance libraries for that like [pycontracts](http://andreacensi.github.com/contracts/).
- Write unittests also to make sure that the whole API works as expected, that is, only the expected types are accepted ([unittest](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html) library works great, but you may want to take a look at alternative runners like [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/) or [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/)).

Regarding `Schedule` being a subclass of `Time`, I agree with the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Would you say that "a schedule is a time" ? I wouldn't. This implies that they don't inherit in this way. I'd say that a schedule is a collection of times, which means that your schedule class will have an attribute which is a listing of times.

Answer (score 0):

Since in Python, type cannot be checked at compile time you need to write something like this on `__init__` of Schedule

```
if not isinstance(start_time, Time):
     raise ValueError("Start time need to be of type time")
```

or

```
assert isinstance(start_time, Time)
```

Similarly for `end_time` also

Answer (score 0):

Generally best practice in Python is to treat it as if it is a `Time` object and simply test whether it has the properties that you want rather than using `isinstance`.   That way someone (including you) could create your own `Time`-like object in the future with the appropriate attributes (`hr`, `min`, `ampm`) and use it as a drop-in replacement.  This would even work–if you aren't doing substantive logic with the `Time` objects or interact with that logic using operators–with their own custom objects that don't use the same fields.  That would have a few good advantages, depending on exactly how your schedule objects work.

This style of coding is known as "[Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp)" and is relatively common in python, thanks to widespread use of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python).

A somewhat better pattern than using `isinstance` that still lets you check whether it conforms to a standard (if you want to do that) might be to use `hasattr` instead.  For example:

`hasattr(start_time, 'ampm')`

I'll also agree with the others that a `Schedule` doesn't seem to have a *is a* relationship with `Time` but rather a *has a* relationship, else you could end up with someone creating a schedule with a `Schedule` as the start time and a `Schedule` as the end time.